# Inno Setup: how to pass parameter while running exe in [Run]

Tags: parameter-passing, inno-setup

How can I pass a custom parameter in [Run] section in Inno Setup?
While I am making use of the following code, the exe is able to get the parameter but I am not able to get the value is, its coming blank.

Following is my code

```
[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\v1700sp3.exe; Parameters: "/APPCONFIGPATH= jjh"; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
```

Following is my code in calling exe

```
[Code]

    function GetCommandLineParam(inParam: String): String;
    var
      LoopVar : Integer;
      BreakLoop : Boolean;
    begin
      { Init the variable to known values }
      LoopVar :=0;
      Result := '';
      BreakLoop := False;
    //RaiseException('ParamCount ' + IntToStr(ParamCount) + ', inParam - ' + inParam ) 
    MsgBox(IntToStr(ParamCount), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      { Loop through the passed in arry to find the parameter }
      while ( (LoopVar < ParamCount) and
              (not BreakLoop) ) do
      begin
        MsgBox(ParamStr(LoopVar), mbInformation, MB_OK);
        { Determine if the looked for parameter is the next value }
        if ( (ParamStr(LoopVar) = inParam) and
             ( (LoopVar+1) <= ParamCount )) then
        begin
          { Set the return result equal to the next command line parameter }
          Result := ParamStr(LoopVar+1);

          { Break the loop }
          BreakLoop := True;
        end;

        { Increment the loop variable }
        LoopVar := LoopVar + 1;
      end;
    end;

    procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
    var
      Filename: String;
      ResultCode: Integer;
      APPCONFIGPATH_Value : String;
    begin
      if CurStep = ssDone then
        begin
          APPCONFIGPATH_Value := GetCommandLineParam('/APPCONFIGPATH');      
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: Remove that space after equal sign.

Comment: Removing space would make the parameter name as "/APPCONFIGPATH=jjh" where as my parameter name is "/APPCONFIGPATH".  As posted in answer section we don't need the equal sign and we can have parameter name <<space>> and value

Comment: No way. If you pass `/APPCONFIGPATH= jjh` with space inside, you'll get it parsed as two parameters! The same applies to what you've posted in your answer. In such case you don't need to bother with passing that `/APPCONFIGPATH` if you don't check it (you would need to check two subsequent `ParamStr`s). Well, maybe that's what your function do, I don't know, I'm lazy to understand how that function works (a quick look disappointed me :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out after little more research that equal '=' sign is not needed. So the updated [Run] section should look like

```
[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\v1700sp3.exe; Parameters: "/APPCONFIGPATH ""jjj"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
```